# Change name space of LINQ to SQL generated classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, namespaces

Is there anyway I can change the namespace of the classes generated by LINQ to SQL

right now it goes ProjectName.FolderName

Is there anyways I can change this default convention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the designer and click on the background, there are two properties called `Entity Namespace` and `Context Namespace`, you can use those to set the namespace for the generated classes.

Comment: This does change the namespace within the LinqToSql files, but it doesn't move the code to the external project who's namespace I gave in the entity namespace.

Answer (score 0):

SQLMetal - Follow [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) specified. But in essence it looks as follows.

```
SqlMetal /server:.\SQLExpress /database:Northwind /pluralize /namespace:nwind /code:Northwind.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

The [LINQ to SQL templates for T4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex might be an option